# Accessing `Auto save` attribute in V-ray's frame buffer

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am working on a Python script that needs to check the state of the V-ray frame buffer attribute check box -history settings, `Auto save` in Autodesk Maya. I am having trouble finding the MEL/Python command to access this setting.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the other name for `Auto save` attribute is `Show/Hide VFB history` if you're trying to access it programmatically.

Here's a Python code:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.vray("vfbControl", "-history", 1)
mc.vray("vfbControl", "-history", 0)
```

And, of course, MEL equivalent:

```
vray vfbControl -history true;
vray vfbControl -history false;
```

You can inspect all the properties here: [Controlling the VFB Programmatically](https://docs.chaosgroup.com/display/VRAY3MAYA/Controlling+the+VFB+Programmatically).

Comment: This is a great link, thank you. In trying the different commands, I can not seem to get the mc.vray("hideVFB") to work. I would also like to hide the VFB programmatically. Thanks!